# Why did HTTP Toolkit suddenly fails for app?

Tags: android, mitmproxy, http-toolkit

I've been using HTTP Toolkit for a few months. It's worked great for viewing traffic in a game from the app store (I've modded the app to view it's traffic). I wanted to try using mitmproxy (rather, mitmweb), but it was going to require its own cert to be installed. I knew that HTTP Toolkit copies the cert folder and remounts, so I thought I'd follow the steps mitmproxy provides to make the certs (http://wiki.cacert.org/FAQ/ImportRootCert#Android_Phones_.26_Tablets) and then connecting with HTTP Toolkit would do it's thing and the mitmproxy certs would get included.

It didn't work.

Now I don't recall why I first rebooted my phone afterwards, but I haven't been able to log in to the app while HTTP Proxy is running since this happened. It used to list everything and just have a line that says "Certificate rejected for ...." but now the app refuses to login with Google Play; even if I have only the target app selected.

Things I've tried:
I've disabled and uninstalled the cert from HTTP Toolkit so it could re-install it.
I think the mitmproxy certs I created ended up not even being in the folder after I started HTTP Toolkit.
I've uninstalled the HTTP Toolkit app.
Rebooted my phone a couple times.
Nothing appears to have changed with the app; it's still the same, latest version.

Comment: Check to root CA certificates by the used proxys. They are often created with a pretty short expiration date ( e.g. just one year after creation). May be your used root CA is already experied?

Comment: mitmproxy never appeared to install. I can see HTTP Toolkit CA, but it says October '23 - October '24; so that one is not expired

Comment: Can you file a bug at https://github.com/httptoolkit/httptoolkit/issues? I'm the maintainer, this sounds like a bug rather than a general support question, and it'll be easier to investigate there. It would be helpful if you could share your HTTP Toolkit logs (Help -> View HTTP Toolkit logs) after rerunning the ADB interception setup for your device, and screenshots of the HTTP Toolkit app running on your phone and any other errors.